# Recursive lookup on Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have multiple tables from which I need to extract Parent/Child info for each item in one of the tables. So for example:

```
Table1:
| id | Name     | ParentIDFromTable2 | Weight | Height |
| 1  | Jack     | 5                  | 180    | 183    |
| 2  | Sparrow  | 3                  | 210    | 169    |
| 3  | John     | 6                  | 350    | 210    |
| 4  | Jill     | 2                  | 110    | 140    |
| 5  | Juliet   | 7                  | 122    | 150    |

Table2:
| id | Name     | GrandParentID     | Location |
| 1  | Adam     | 0                 | Earth    |
| 2  | Zack     | 1                 | Earth    |
| 3  | Noah     | 2                 | Earth    |
| 4  | Jacob    | 3                 | Earth    |
| 5  | Jeff     | 4                 | Earth    |
| 6  | Drake    | 5                 | Earth    |
| 7  | Kanye    | 3                 | Earth    |
```

So for each row in Table1, I want to be able to extract the full paternity hierarchy along with that row's attributes so for example for Table1 entries:

ID=1 >>> Name=Jack, Weight=180, Height=183, Lineage= Earth/Adam/Zack/Noah/Jacob/Jeff/Jack

ID=5 >>> Name=Juliet, Weight=122, Height=150, Lineage= Earth/Adam/Zack/Noah/Kanye/Juliet

I've tried using with recursive lookup but can't figure out how to do recursion for ParentIDs from Table2

Comment: Why is 'Earth' concatenated in your expected results? It is a Location concatenated with Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE and `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function to concatenate the locations:

```
WITH 
  target AS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id = 1),
  cte AS (
    SELECT *, 1 level FROM Table2 WHERE id = (SELECT ParentIDFromTable2 FROM target)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.*, c.level + 1 
    FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.GrandParentID = t2.id
  )
SELECT *,
      (SELECT Location || '/' || 
              GROUP_CONCAT(Name, '/') OVER (ORDER BY level DESC) FROM cte ORDER BY level LIMIT 1
      ) || '/' || Name Lineage
FROM target;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qf8OdwPz).

Comment: this worked perfectly - Thank You! I tried modifying it for a different use case but can't figure out the conditional part - I've posted a separate question for that one here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76324144/8729576