# Recursive lookup on Multiple Tables with conditional

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursive-query

I have multiple tables from which I need to extract Parent/Child info for each item in one of the tables. So for example:

Table1:

| id | Name | ParentIDFromTable2 | Weight | Height | Description | LocationIDFromTable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 5 | 180 | 183 | T1Desc1 | 1 |
| 2 | Sparrow | 3 | 210 | 169 | T1Desc2 | 1 |
| 3 | John | 6 | 350 | 210 | T1Desc3 | 1 |
| 4 | Jill | 1 | 110 | 140 | T1Desc4 | 2 |
| 5 | Juliet | 7 | 122 | 150 | T1Desc5 | 1 |

Table2:

| id | Name | GrandParentID | IDFromTable3 | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 0 | 1 | Des1 |
| 2 | >Zack | 1 | 1 | Des2 |
| 3 | Noah | 2 | 1 | Des3 |
| 4 | Jacob | 3 | 1 | Des4 |
| 5 | >Jeff | 4 | 1 | Des5 |
| 6 | Drake | 5 | 1 | Des6 |
| 7 | Kanye | 3 | 1 | Des7 |

Table3:

| id | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 | D1 |
| 2 | P2 | D2 |
| 3 | P3 | D3 |

So for each item in Table1, it should return the full parental hierarchy along with the description from Table2 IF the Name field in Table2 contains > character AND Only use the description from the first Name field with the > character. So for example:

| ID | Name | Weight | Height | Description | Lineage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 180 | 183 | Des5 | P1/Adam/Zack/Noah/Jacob/Jeff/Jack |
| 4 | Jill | 110 | 140 | T1Desc4 | P2/Adam/Jill |
| 5 | Juliet | 122 | 150 | Des2 | P1/Adam/Zack/Noah/Kanye/Juliet |

I'd asked a similar question and thought I would be able to figure out the conditional description but no luck so far.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

**[UPDATE]**
For clarification:

1. In Table2, the Location Column holds the IDs of Table3 - thus for clarity I've update the Location column to IDFromTable3 in Table2
2. the challenge for me is to introduce a check while doing recursion such that IF there exists in Table2 Name column a '>' character, then the item in Table1's Description shall be updated to the description from Table2's first occurrence (of > character - if for example during recursion on Table2 more than 1 GrandParentID items are encountered that have '>' character in the Name column) else it shall use the description from its own (Table1) row
3. I've fixed the Table1 to reflect the updated column LocationIDFromTable3 -- so in other words we can use the Table3 ID directly from Table1 instead of going to Table2

Comment: How is Table3 related to the other tables? Why is there P1 in Lineage of all rows of your expected results?

Comment: Why is `Sparrow` not in your output, but `Jill` is?

Comment: @forpas (not OP). While it isn't explained about Table3, it looks like the starting point of recursion is table1, table2 is where the recursion actually happens, and then table3 would be joined after recursion to the last node found. Sort of: `WITH RECURSIVE cte AS( SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM cte JOIN table2) SELECT * FROM cte JOIN table3` type of outline. (grain of salt here since I'm making some assumptions).

Comment: @forpas - so Table2 has Location which is the ID from Table3

Comment: @JNevill - i only included a couple examples in the output, but yea technically for all rows  in Table1 there must exist a corresponding output row

Comment: @forpas - how can I modify your original query to achieve the result above?

Comment: Can you explain why the Description for ID = 1 should be Des5 (Jeff's) and for ID = 5 it should be Des2 (Zack's)?

Comment: @forpas - that is because if you observe, Jack's ParentIDFromTable2 is 5, since in Table2 for id=5 the name field contains the > character, thus the description for Jack should return the FIRST corresponding > character description from Table2 (basically overwrite Jacks Description with the first occurence of Description IF > character is found in the name field when checking recursion for ParentIDFromTable2).

Comment: @forpas - I ask since your query was blazingly fast and I was hoping to leverage that!

Comment: Which is the location you match with in the final table, the location of the tab1 id or the location of the first `>`-tagged child?

Comment: @lemon - give me 2 min, I will fix the Tables -- there is Location in Table1 and Table2 -- so we can either use Table1's Location (which refers to Table3 IDs) OR Table2's Location which refers to Table3's IDs -- sorry about the confusion, Im gonna update the Table1

Comment: @lemon - I've updated Table1 and the output for Jill (shows P2 since we're relying on the LocationIDFromTable3 ID to grab Table3 ID, sorry about the confusion!)

Comment: I've updated one last time my answer, I hope that can fit you right away, or help you find a solution by looking at what is done inside the subqueries and adapting to your needs. This recursion problem is just more complex than your previous one, and the solution inherits that same complexity.

Comment: This is a different requirement than your previous question and the use of the code that solved that is not possible. Try the query in my current answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE and aggregation utilising [SQLite's feature of bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, Name, Weight, Height, Description, Name Lineage, ParentIDFromTable2, LocationIDFromTable3, 
             false flag, 0 level 
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.Name, c.Weight, c.Height, 
         CASE WHEN NOT flag AND t2.Name LIKE '>%' THEN t2.Description ELSE c.Description END, 
         TRIM(t2.Name, '>') || '/' || c.Lineage,
         t2.GrandParentID,
         c.LocationIDFromTable3,
         flag OR t2.Name LIKE '>%',
         c.level + 1
  FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN cte c 
  ON c.ParentIDFromTable2 = t2.id
)
SELECT t.id, t.Name, t.Weight, t.Height, t.Description, 
       t3.Name || '/' || t.Lineage Lineage 
FROM (SELECT *, MAX(level) FROM cte GROUP BY id) t 
INNER JOIN Table3 t3
ON t3.id = t.LocationIDFromTable3
GROUP BY t.id;
```

If the char `'>'` may be anywhere inside the value of `Name` in `Table2` and not only at the beginning, then replace `t2.Name LIKE '>%'` with `INSTR(t2.Name, '>')`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/v8AFnvtp).

Comment: Great answer and interesting showcased sqlite features to be learning from.

Comment: This works great and is the runtime on my actual dataset is 8s vs 13s for the answer from lemon. Thank you both for showing me different approaches!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with recursion:

- "*Base step*": gather information from tab1
- "*Recursive step*": join step n-1 cte with tab2 on matching `cte.ParentIDFromTable2 = tab2.id`. Make `>`-prefixed names to have their description recognizable, by concatenating the very same character at the beginning.

Once recursion is done, you can:

- gather the first relevant description with `FIRST_VALUE`, and order records to...
- make aggregation using `GROUP_CONCAT` on names, to get your lineage
- lastly join with tab3 to gather ancestor infos

each carried out in a subquery.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id AS firstId, name AS firstName, 
           NULL AS lastId, name, ParentIDFromTable2, Weight, Height,
           Description, LocationIDFromTable3 AS Location
    FROM tab1

    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT cte.firstId, cte.firstName, 
           tab2.id, TRIM(tab2.Name, '>'), tab2.GrandParentID, NULL, NULL, 
           CASE WHEN SUBSTR(tab2.Name, 0, 2)='>' 
                THEN '>' || tab2.Description
           END AS Description, NULL
    FROM       cte 
    INNER JOIN tab2
            ON cte.ParentIDFromTable2 = tab2.id
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT firstId, firstName, Weight, Height, name, lastId,
           FIRST_VALUE(Description) OVER(
               PARTITION BY firstId 
               ORDER     BY Description IS NULL,
                            SUBSTR(name, 0, 2)='>' DESC, 
                            lastid DESC
           ) AS Description, 
           Location
    FROM cte 
    ORDER BY firstId, ParentIDFromTable2
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT firstId                 AS id, 
           firstName               AS name,
           MAX(Weight)             AS weight,
           MAX(Height)             AS height,
           MIN(Description)        AS description,
           MAX(Location)           AS location,
           GROUP_CONCAT(name, '/') AS lineage
    FROM cte2 
    GROUP BY firstId, 
             firstName
)
SELECT cte3.id, 
       cte3.name, 
       cte3.weight, 
       cte3.height, 
       TRIM(cte3.description, '>') AS description, 
       tab3.name || '/' || cte3.lineage AS lineage
FROM       cte3
INNER JOIN tab3
        ON tab3.id = cte3.location
```

**Output**:

| id | name | weight | height | description | lineage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | 180 | 183 | Des5 | P1/Adam/Zack/Noah/Jacob/Jeff/Jack |
| 2 | Sparrow | 210 | 169 | Des2 | P1/Adam/Zack/Noah/Sparrow |
| 3 | John | 350 | 210 | Des5 | P1/Adam/Zack/Noah/Jacob/Jeff/Drake/John |
| 4 | Jill | 110 | 140 | T1Desc4 | P1/Adam/Jill |
| 5 | Juliet | 122 | 150 | Des2 | P1/Adam/Zack/Noah/Kanye/Juliet |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9quZ7SkPjLafUWxyJXD2mP/6).

---

**EDIT**: An attempt at removing some of the columns to be added at the end is the following:

- keep all the necessary, to be updated, columns in the recursion cte,
- add a last join operation to recover the fields you were missing

In the following example, we're going to remove the fields "*weight*" and "*height*", to add them in the last step.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id AS firstId, name AS firstName, 
           NULL AS lastId, name, ParentIDFromTable2,
           Description, LocationIDFromTable3 AS Location
    FROM tab1

    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT cte.firstId, cte.firstName, 
           tab2.id, TRIM(tab2.Name, '>'), tab2.GrandParentID, 
           CASE WHEN SUBSTR(tab2.Name, 0, 2)='>' 
                THEN '>' || tab2.Description
           END AS Description, NULL
    FROM       cte 
    INNER JOIN tab2
            ON cte.ParentIDFromTable2 = tab2.id
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT firstId, firstName, name, lastId,
           FIRST_VALUE(Description) OVER(
               PARTITION BY firstId 
               ORDER     BY Description IS NULL,
                            SUBSTR(name, 0, 2)='>' DESC, 
                            lastid DESC
           ) AS Description, 
           Location
    FROM cte 
    ORDER BY firstId, ParentIDFromTable2
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT firstId                 AS id, 
           firstName               AS name,
           MIN(Description)        AS description,
           MAX(Location)           AS location,
           GROUP_CONCAT(name, '/') AS lineage
    FROM cte2 
    GROUP BY firstId, 
             firstName
)
SELECT cte3.id, 
       cte3.name, 
       tab1.weight, 
       tab1.height, 
       TRIM(cte3.description, '>') AS description, 
       tab3.Name || '/' || cte3.lineage AS lineage
FROM       cte3
INNER JOIN tab1 
        ON tab1.id = cte3.id
INNER JOIN tab3
        ON tab1.LocationIDFromTable3 = tab3.id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9quZ7SkPjLafUWxyJXD2mP/7).

Comment: is there a way to return ALL columns of Table 1 without specifying them individually (in my actual db I have lot more columns that I do want returned)?

Comment: Mh I don't think so... and if that's a way (I'm thinking to join operations), that's just going to impact performance further negatively.

Comment: Check edit on the updated answer. @Salvatore

Comment: yea this is taking very long indeed, on my actual dataset it took 13s (using Ryzen 7950x), also theres an issue with this code wherein the Location from Table2 seems to be hardcoded to always return 1 - if you change any entry in Table2's Location to 2 (currently all set to 1) - it fails to grab the corresponding Name from Table3 and just shows P1 for all

Comment: Probably it's better to add that relationship inside the post. Now the query should be updated to reflect that relationship as well.

Comment: Its still not updating the Location (in your demo change the Location for any item to 2) - observe it still shows P1 when it should've shown P2

Comment: You should probably add more description around Location values in your post. It's not clear how they come in play so far, to me at least.

Comment: I've added some additional description, i hope it clarifies what Im trying to achieve